# How the function restClient(url) is not being called whenevr DOMContentLoaded event fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + "ranchi" + "&units=metric";

      restClient(url);

      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getWeatherByLocation);

    });



     function getWeatherByLocation() {`......do some work here..

    var url=.....;  

    restClient(url);
    }`

    function restClient(url) {....//do some work here...

document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="Something to write"..;
}
```

`restClient()` is the function which ultmiatly writes on the `HTML` page,now the question is first time `DOMContetnLoaded` The `restClient` is called and it writes on `HTML` page,then the next line is executes which is:  `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',getWeatherByLocation);`
 when someones trigger the button, and ultimately the function `restClient` is agin called from the `getWeatherByLocation` function,
but  when some one again triggers the button ,how the line 4 is executed again.

I think before executing line 4 again,the line 2,3 must be executed if i am not wrong?

And

Comment: If `getWeatherByLocation` will not reload the DOM, why would line 2 and 3 be called again? Or am i miss understanding your question?

Comment: Mangled edit makes the question near-impossible to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`DOMContentLoaded` fires only once, when the page loads the first time.

If you want that other code to execute every time you run `getWeatherByLocation`, it should be moved to the end of the `getWeatherByLocation` function.

See the docs for `DOMContentLoaded`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: furthermore, domcontentloaded is usually not the right place for a content script. depending on the extension load mode it could never get called.

Comment: Oh, you are 100% right! Sorry I totally missed the chrome extension tag!